# Flutter says RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded

Tags: flutter, dart

**i want to make gridview of elearning page and call data from API(Postman) but unfortunately, I get this error:**

> Another exception was thrown: RenderFlex children have non-zero flex
> but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
>
> Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
> RenderFlex#92214 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT
> NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
>
> Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
> RenderFlex#79539 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
>
> Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
> RenderConstrainedBox#1c3d5 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
> NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
>
> Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
> RenderRepaintBoundary#1943e relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT
> NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
>
> Another exception was thrown:
> 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed
> assertion: line 544 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is    not true.
>
> Another exception was thrown: Null check operator used on a null value
>
> Another exception was thrown: Null check operator used on a null value
> I/flutter (14832): CacheManager: Failed to download file from
> a8fawUT6lZk with error: I/flutter (14832): Invalid argument(s): No
> host specified in URI a8fawUT6lZk

**I want to make like this :**

[image]

This is my `elearningscreen.dart` file :

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:e_digital_nepal/api/http_services.dart';
import 'package:e_digital_nepal/model/e-learning/elearning.dart';
import 'package:e_digital_nepal/provider/e-learning_provider.dart';
import 'package:e_digital_nepal/util/form_data.dart';
import 'package:e_digital_nepal/util/global_config.dart';
import 'package:e_digital_nepal/util/services/toastr_service.dart';
import 'package:pull_to_refresh/pull_to_refresh.dart';

import '../../../../widgets/widget.dart';
import 'package:e_digital_nepal/provider/mainProvider.dart';
import 'package:e_digital_nepal/screen/login/e-learning/student/detail_online_resource.dart';
import 'package:e_digital_nepal/util/utility.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'grid_view_info.dart';

class ELearningStudentScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ELearningStudentScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ELearningStudentScreen> createState() => _ELearningStudentScreenState();
}

class _ELearningStudentScreenState extends State<ELearningStudentScreen> {
  HttpRepo _httpRepo = HttpServices();
  bool _isLoading = true;
  bool infiniteLoading = false;
  int pageNumber = 1;
  List<StudentOnlineResource> onlineresources = [];
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  late AnimationController controller;
  RefreshController _refreshController =
      RefreshController(initialRefresh: false);
  ToastrService _toastr = ToastrService();

  fetchInit(int page) async {
    try {
      var userInfo = context.read<MainProvider>().studentUser;
      Map<String, dynamic> body = <String, dynamic>{
        "studentId": userInfo.id,
        "teamId": userInfo.teamId,
        "pageNumber": 1,
        // "currentVideoId": "",
        // "subjectId": ""
      };
      DataUtility.getFormData(body);
      var data = DataUtility.getFormData(body);
      // var url = '/student/online-resource/student-wise';

      var response =
          await _httpRepo.post('/student/online-resource/student-wise', data);
      print('Response:: $response');
      print(response.body.toString());
      if (response.body.length == 0) {
        _toastr.showDefaultToaster('No more data found');
      }
      var studentOnlineResources =
          studentOnlineResourceFromJson(json.encode(response.body));
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
        onlineresources = [...onlineresources, ...studentOnlineResources];
      });
    } catch (e) {}
  }

  void _onRefresh() async {
    setState(() {
      pageNumber = 1;
      _isLoading = true;
      onlineresources = [];
    });
    await fetchInit(1);
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
    _refreshController.refreshCompleted();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchInit(1);
    _scrollController.addListener(() async {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels >=
          _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        setState(() {
          infiniteLoading = true;
        });
        await fetchInit(pageNumber + 1);
        setState(() {
          pageNumber = pageNumber + 1;
          infiniteLoading = false;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _scrollController.dispose();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _mainProvider = Provider.of<MainProvider>(context, listen: false);
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: CoustomAppBar(
          title: 'Online Resources',
          isCenterTitle: true,
        ),
        body: _isLoading
            ? ListLoader()
            : SmartRefresher(
                controller: _refreshController,
                onRefresh: _onRefresh,
                enablePullDown: true,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  controller: _scrollController,
                  itemCount: onlineresources.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return SizedBox(
                      height: 200,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          GridViewInfo(
                            onlineStudentResource: onlineresources[index],
                          ),
                          if (infiniteLoading &&
                              onlineresources[index].id ==
                                  onlineresources[onlineresources.length - 1]
                                      .id)
                            // ChangeNotifierProvider<ELearningProvider>(
                            //   create: (context) => ELearningProvider(
                            //       context, _mainProvider.loginInfo),
                            //   child: Consumer<ELearningProvider>(
                            //     builder: (_, _provider, child) => Padding(
                            //       padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                            //       child: OrientationBuilder(
                            //           builder: (context, orientation) {
                            //         return GridView.builder(
                            //             gridDelegate:
                            //                 SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                            //                     maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
                            //                     childAspectRatio: 0.5,
                            //                     crossAxisSpacing: 16,
                            //                     mainAxisSpacing: 16),
                            //             itemCount: 3,
                            //             itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                            //               return Container(
                            //                 child: GridViewInfo(
                            //                   onlineStudentResource:
                            //                       onlineresources[index],
                            //                 ),
                            //                 decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            //                     color: Colors.white,
                            //                     border: Border.all(
                            //                       color: Colors.grey,
                            //                       width: 1,
                            //                     ),
                            //                     borderRadius:
                            //                         BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                            //               );
                            //             });
                            //       }),
                            //     ),
                            //   ),
                            // ),
                            Column(
                              children: [
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 20,
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 5,
                                  width: width - 50,
                                  child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                                    backgroundColor:
                                        Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
                                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                    semanticsLabel: 'Linear progress indicator',
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 10,
                                ),
                              ],
                            )
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ));
  }
}



//  GridViewInfo(
//                           onlineStudentResource: onlineresources[index],
//                         ),
//                         if (infiniteLoading &&
//                             onlineresources[index].id ==
//                                 onlineresources[onlineresources.length - 1].id)
```

Comment: `GridViewInfo ` wrap with expanded and remove the `SizedBox`

Answer (score 0):

wrap `GridViewInfo` in `Expanded` because you are using scrollable view in the column you should give the size of the scrollable area

```dart
Expanded(
   child: GridViewInfo()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Expanded`. Wrap `GridViewInfo` inside of the `Expanded` widget. If you are a beginner and do not know how `Expanded` widget works you can check the documentation. In future you will face this kind of issues a lot so you should better learn the usage of `Expanded` and `Flexible` widgets.

```
Expanded(
   child: YourCustomWidget(),// That is your GridViewInfo() widget
),
```

Documentation link: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html
Video link: https://youtu.be/_rnZaagadyo